# Finding Tension in a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, centripetal-force

[image: picture]

When trying to find the tension in the string, can you find the centripetal force and subtract it from the weight of the bob? i.e. $\frac{mv^2}{r}+mg=T$.

Also, can you do $Tcos\theta=mg$ to find T too? (Theta being the angle in the diagram below)

[image]

Reason why I'm asking is because in a question I tried both ways, in the first way I got 2.09N, in the second way I got 2.03N, not sure why there is a difference in answers - so wondering if there's a misunderstanding in my concepts here.

Comment: Have a look here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/733259

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forces on simple pendulum bob at turning point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/733257/forces-on-simple-pendulum-bob-at-turning-point)

Comment: honestly no. I don't really see how the questions relate exactly/most of your answer in that question I can't really understand. (high school level)

Comment: I think $T= \frac{mv^2}{r} +mg\;cos \theta$

Comment: https://prnt.sc/GHyRTthWbzdB (marking scheme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{mv^2}{r}+mg=T$ is incorrect because the tension and the bob's weight act in different directions. You must have some dependence on $\theta$ in here, otherwise the tension in the string would be constant.

$T\cos\theta=mg$ is also incorrect because it implies that the net vertical force on the bob is zero - but we know this is not correct because the bob is accelerating vertically as well as horizontally.

The correct approach is to resolve forces along the line of the string. We have the tension $T$ acting towards the pivot and a component of the bob's weight $mg \cos \theta$ acting in the opposite direction. The net sum of these must equal the centripetal force that is required to keep the bob moving along a circle. So we have

$\displaystyle T - mg\cos\theta = \frac {mv^2}r$

or

$\displaystyle T = mg\cos\theta + \frac {mv^2}r$

It is a common misconception to think that the centripetal force is a third force acting on the bob. There are only two forces acting on the bob - the tension in the string and its weight - and the component of the net sum of these two forces along the line of the string must equal the centripetal force needed to keep the bob moving in a  circle